# how to merge object of multiple json into one json file using node.js

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, shell, loops

I have multiple json files which just want to merge particular object from them and then save it into new json file:
for example:

```
one.json
two.json
...
```

**and each json file is like this:**

**one.json**

```
{
  "passed": 1,
  "fixtures": [
    {
      "name": "Getting Started one",
      "path": "testOne.ts"
    }
  ]
}
```

**two.json**

```
{
  "passed": 1,
  "fixtures": [
    {
      "name": "Getting Started two",
      "path": "testTwo.ts"
    }
  ]
}
```

**so my final json file should be like this:**

**final.json**

```
{
    "passed": 2,
    "fixtures": [{
            "name": "Getting Started one",
            "path": "testOne.ts"
        },
        {
            "name": "Getting Started two",
            "path": "testTwo.ts"
        }
    ]
}
```

do you have an idea what is the simple way to merge like this.

node: json files is not just two but many so it is good to find every file which has a extension of json.
it is good to do this in shell script or node.js.

thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can do something like this using Promise:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const data = {
    "passed": 0,
    "fixtures": []
};
const dir = `${__dirname}/data/`;
fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        files.forEach(file => {
           console.log(file);
           let content = require(`${dir}${file}`);
           data['passed'] += content.passed;
           data['fixtures'] = data['fixtures'].concat(content['fixtures']);
        });
        resolve(data);
    }).then(data => {
        fs.writeFileSync('./final.json',JSON.stringify(data));
    });
})
```

Using Async/Await it can done like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const dir = path.join(__dirname, 'data');

let finalContent = { "fixtures": [], "passed": 0 };
const read_directory = async dir =>
    fs.readdirSync(dir).reduce((finalContent, file) => {
        filePath = path.join(dir, file);
        console.log(filePath);
        let content = require(filePath);
        finalContent.passed += content.passed;
        finalContent.fixtures = finalContent.fixtures.concat(content.fixtures);
        return finalContent;
    }, { "passed": 0, "fixtures": [] });

read_directory(dir).then(data => {
    fs.writeFileSync('./final.json', JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

Comment: thanks for your great solution, i have revised the question, actually i have  adding another object into each json which is not array, but number , and in a final json it should be the sum of all number, do have solution for this situation. thanks

Comment: Updated, have a look

Answer (score 0):

First, deserialize the JSON into the object and put all the objects into a list and then serialize the list object to JSON.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, if you want to do it by node.js, you can use one of the node packages, that will make it for you very easy. For example, it's a good merge json package -   https://www.npmjs.com/package/package-merge